# Used games: Xbox One S

Tags: xbox-one

I recently purchased 3 used games for my Xbox one S. They are as follows:

1. Gears of War 4
2. Tom Clancy’s rainbow six siege
3. Call of duty ghosts

I had a couple of questions in mind, since this is the first time of me buying used games.

1. What about the ownership of the game? For example when I buy a brand new game I’m technically the owner since I’m the one who bought it first. But in the case of used games since someone else is the owner will I be the new owner once I purchase it?
2. Will it by any chance damage my console? ( better be safe than sorry:-( )
3. Does my console by any chance know that the game is used?

I haven’t installed those games as yet. So if anyone could help me I would truly appreciate your help. I don’t want to regret buying these in the future.

Comment: You wouldn't even be able to rent games if any of these were the case.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill yeah, you’re right. But still this is my first time and I have absolutely no experience buying used. I don’t want to damage my console cause my parents would be unhappy then. And this is the reason why I haven’t even installed them. Wanted to clear these questions in my mind and then install them. Don’t want to regret in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You're the owner since you purchased the item off a retailer / other user. Nothing else to it
2. If a game disc was edited in such a way (any way idk how), the console would probably reject trying to read off it because of it's new format
3. The console doesn't have any previous data of the game. For all that knows, it's a brand new game straight from the line.

Very weird questions. This seems to be some pent up paranoia. Used copies are fine, just check for obvious surface scratches. Scratches on a disc (when they're deep-ish) prevent the console from reading from it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Yes indeed it’s paranoia cause this is my first time buying used games and for me buying used is like buying a used computer or phone or something. Anyways thanks again!

Comment: those examples you give are also both plenty safe buying used...

Comment: Your only issue is if the game came with download codes (e.g. DLC for a day one edition) . If the codes were redeemed, then you wouldn't be able to use those codes.

Comment: @pboss3010 they are just the standard edition which is disc based